Aeronautics - How did the word originate?
It's a well known fact that the Wright brothers invented the aeroplane. I read on a quiz for children:

The Wright brothers were raised by parents who insisted their sons get a good education. Their mother taught them basic mechanics and later, they studied aeronautics. They found the idea of flight fascinating, and they invented a remarkable machine that changed travel forever.
What was it?

As per the Cambridge dictionary:

aeronautics.
noun [ U ].
the science of designing, building, and operating aircraft

Now I am confused which came first -  "Aeroplanes or Aeronautics" ?
How could they teach "aeronautics" to the inventors of aeroplanes?
Edit 1.
The earlier meaning of "aeronaut" (air sailor) was different and not the dictionary meaning. A successful working aeroplane was first flown only by the Wright brothers.

Which came first: biology or biologics?

@Lambie I have a doubt you are the one giving down votes to all my posts - even grammar posts which are getting a lot of views.

If you have a doubt, it's not me, right? I have downvoted a couple but not all. The sentence says they studied it; it does not say anyone taught them aeronautics. People can study things on their own. The problem is that this question is not really about English.

Cayley and the foundation of modern aeronautics
Sir George Cayley (1773–1857) is widely acknowledged as the founder of modern aeronautics. He was first called the "father of the aeroplane" in 1846[16] and Henson called him the "father of aerial navigation."[3] He was the first true scientific aerial investigator to publish his work, which included for the first time the underlying principles and forces of flight.[17]
In 1809 he began the publication of a landmark three-part treatise titled "On Aerial Navigation" (1809–1810) Wikipedia.

Wikipedia's page Aeronautics mentions the 9th century polymath Abbas ibn Firnas, Leonardo da Vinci (1452-1519), and Cayley as among the first to study the science of flight; the word itself is newer but no reason it can't be applied to the older efforts. (And, by comparison, many people theorised about space flight long before the first rocket took off - at least those studying flight in the atmosphere could study birds and insects.)

@StuartF aeronautics.
noun [ U ].
the science of designing, building, and operating aircraft. This meaning is from Cambridge dictionary. Aeronautics is not studying flight of insects and birds.

The questions in the body (Now I am confused which came first - "Aeroplanes or Aeronautics" ? and How could they teach "aeronautics" to the inventors of aeroplanes? ) are very different from the title.

I think the passage is slightly misleading; the Wright brothers didn't 'study aeronautics' as part of their education. According to Wikipedia, they first worked as printers and later had a bicycle shop.
The word aeronaut (air sailor) had been coined a century earlier to refer to the first balloonists. By the 1890s, people were experimenting with gliders (launched from hilltops) and with powered flight, and the Wrights 'studied' these developments in the sense of researching into them, not learning about them in a school.

If the word "aeronaut" was coined earlier, then the passage isn't misleading. It doesn't mention they studied as part of their education. Their mother taught them basic mechanics.

No, it doesn't explicitly say so, but I had the impression that you understood it that way - that someone else taught them about aeronautics.

And aeronautics was coined in 1824. The OED gives the quotation, from the Encyclopedia Britannica, "We prefer, as more correct and appropriate, the word Aeronautics, now generally adopted to express aërial navigation."

The Wright brothers flew gliders before making their powered flyer. Gliders involve all the same forces as airplanes.

Not all the same forces, @SoronelHaetir.  As explained on a page from NASA’s Glenn Research Center, “Compared to a powered aircraft, we see that a glider has only three main forces acting on it: lift, drag, and weight.” Having no engines, they lack any source of the fourth force, thrust.

My guess is that the quotation marks give you your answer. Assuming you have correctly copied the paragraph, the quotation marks tell us that the word is anachronistic. Effectively the writer is saying that they studied the elements of what would later become known as aeronautics.

Though, apparently, the word aeronaut was coined in the late 18th century for travellers in hot-air balloons.

@KateBunting I think some other people tried to fly before Wright brothers. They might have developed the theory.
